# Angular - how to block the action of changing the checkbox value visually and logically and change it only after the user confirms the alert

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a problem when using angular, I would like that when I click on a checkbox, it doesn't stay checked or change its value, and that only happens after the user confirms a window.alert

```
<div class="mr-3 ml-3">
   <label class="switch">
   <input
   [disabled]="!isEdit"
   #input
   type="checkbox"
   [checked]="item.status"
   [(ngModel)]="item.status"
   />
   <span class="slider round"></span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you pass the isEdit variable to false when opening the alert, you can do this:

```
// CSS
.lockClick{
  pointer-events: none !important;
}
```

```
// HTML
<input [ngClass]="{'lockClick': !isEdit}" #input type="checkbox"[checked]="item.status" [(ngModel)]="item.status"
   />
``
```

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:

#> <input [disabled]="!isEdit" #input  type="checkbox" [checked]="item.status (change)="item.status=!item.status"/> </span  #